# Stop zip from making whole directory infrastructure inside the archive

Tags: bash, zip

I want to make zip archives on all the directories in a particular path. I am doing this:

```
for dir in ~/user/profiles/data/*; do zip -r $dir.zip $dir ; done
```

Though this is creating the archive, but the issue is it creates the whole directory infrastructure inside the archive.

For example `directory_1` has a file `text.txt` I expect `directory_1.zip` to also contains `text.txt` in it. But instead `directory_1.zip` contains `/user/profiles/data/text.txt`.

What I want to get the same folder and structure once I unzip the archive.

Comment: I don't see this behavior. For me, `zip` is stripping the leading slash. I get paths like `home/kaz/whatever` in the file not `/home/kaz/whatever`. What `zip` program are you using?

Comment: The `zip` utility from Info-Zip doesn't have any option for shortening the paths stored in the archive (e.g. by stripping some leading prefix or number of components). I don't see anything for renaming the names already in the archive. So the only recourse is to change to the directory you want and create the archive using relative paths from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the paths in the archive to be relative to the starting directory, you should change to that directory and then give the program a relative path:

```
dest=$PWD
(cd ~/user/profiles/data &&
   for dir in *
   do zip -r "$dest/$dir.zip" "$dir"
   done)
```

Note the correct quoting of `"$dir"`. Using untrusted filenames without quotes is simply dangerous.

If you don't even want the single directory path in the archive, then a small change achieves that:

```
dest=$PWD
for dir in ~/user/profiles/*
do (cd "$dir" && zip -r "$dest/${dir##*/}.zip" .)
done
```